# Should I send a follow up mail to my potential supervisor

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

Last friday I received an email from my potential supervisor that my application was positively reviewed and that they will further progress with my application if I'm still interested. I replied that I'm happy to hear that and that I'm still interested. However, up until now, I didn't hear from them anymore. Is this normal? I though they would invite me for an interview as soon as possible. I know I might be panicking, but I'm afraid they forgot me. Can I send a second email to ask what the next steps are? Or should I just be patient...

Answer (score 0):

You *are* panicking indeed. Give it some more time.

This was last Friday, and I assume your response was also on Friday. However, that was only **two** working days ago, and this supervisor is probably now in the progress of furthering the application. This probably means filling in some form, possibly requesting availability from potential relevant others that should be involved in the process, HR/administrative tasks, there's lots of reasons why they didn't respond yet.

The fact that they reviewed you application positively should give you enough ease to just wait it out a few more days (weeks maybe even). If you haven't heard anything back in a weeks time you could consider following up and indeed asking what the next steps are. But for now, be patient and be happy that they want to continue with you.